# random forest package in R

Tags: r, random-forest, mse

I use random forest package in R for regression, it gives me two kind of information: `Mean of squared residuals` and % Var explained. But I wanna calculate the `RMSE` and `R^2` of the training and test sets, can anyone help me how can I find these kind of information?

Comment: Please provide a minimally reproducible example of your code with library dependencies and any functions you used.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry this is not a specific answer, but I do not have enough cred to leave a comment.

It is tough to say how you may get at what you want without a reproducible example. However, if you used the `xtest=` and `ytest=` arguments in the call to `randomForest` (assuming you are using the "randomForest" package), then what you are looking for should be a part of the resulting randomForest object. What you want to look in is the `test` part of the resulting random forest list.

An attempted example:

```
rf.results <- randomForest( whatever arguments )
rf.results$test$mse  # mse (maybe you can take the square root to get rmse)
rf.results$test$rsq  # pseudo-R2 for random forest
```

If you have the random forest package loaded you can validate this information as well as do some exploration yourself with `?randomForest`. The "Value" section of the documentation details the object that results from a call to `randomForest` and where you can find various performance metrics.

Comment: Thank you, but two more question: 1: with rf.results$mse, can I calculate the mse and rsq of training set? and the second question, why I got a vector as results!!!? in fact, I need just one real as mse and rsq. but it gives me one mse and one rsq for each sample of data, I think. what should I do?

Comment: `rf.results$mse` will give you the mse of the training set and `rf.results$rsq` will give the pseudo-R2 for the training set. The mse and rsq from rf.results$test are performance measures on the validation set. You should use these to find the optimal number of trees to have in the forest.The reason you get a vector of results is because of the `ntree` argument. You get performance measures for the random forests consisting of 1 to `ntree` trees.